# Wanderwort origins and the Indus Valley Civilization?

Tags: etymology, history

I have noticed that there seem to be many words that have travelled the globe due to trade, such as the word orange or rice, which have plausible origins in proto-Dravidian. Meanwhile, it is hypothesized that the language (if it is a language, which some people argue against) recorded in the Indus script is a Dravidian one. All this makes me wonder if these numerous possibly-Dravidian Wanderworts are indicative of the Indus Valley Civilization's success in trade.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Sanskrit_origin) of Wikipedia lists 7 English words with possible Dravidian origins, notably:

- **Orange**, through Old French orenge, Medieval Latin orenge and Italian arancia from Arabic نارنج naranj, via Persian نارنگ narang and Sanskrit नारङ्ग naranga-s meaning "an orange tree", derived from proto-Dravidian.
- **Rice**, via Old French ris and Italian riso from Latin oriza, which is from Greek ὄρυζα oryza, through an Indo-Iranian tongue finally from Sanskrit व्रीहिस् vrihi-s "rice", derived from proto-Dravidian.
- **Sugar**, through Old French sucre, Italian zucchero, Medieval Latin succarum, Arabic: سكر sukkar and Persian: شکر shakar ultimately from Sanskrit शर्करा sharkara which means "ground or candied sugar" (originally "grit" or "gravel"), from proto-Dravidian.

So, is it likely that the Dravidian language that these words came from is the language of the Indus Valley Civilization? Is this a poor, uninformed idea? or, alternatively, am I late to the party and this is already intuitively obvious to historians? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Did the Indus Valley civilization eat oranges, rice, and sugar? [This webpage](http://www.indianetzone.com/52/food_indus_valley_civilization.htm) says they ate barley, melon, and pomegranates, but I suppose they could have eaten oranges and rice as well. Anyway, it's not an English question, so we probably will close it. You could ask it on linguistics.SE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about English but proto-Dravidian.

Comment: @PeterShor I agree, but I asked this elsewhere and they referred me here saying that the historical linguists hang out here. I also initially thought it would not be suited for a discussion of English, but what they said made sense and I figured it was worth a try.

Comment: This question asks about the possibly shared etymology of 3 English words: orange, rice and sugar. How is that off-topic?